# OnTouch/OnClick listeners. Use both?

Tags: android

I have a short question. Should I use in same time OnTouch and OnClick listeners ?
If I`m correct one is for touch screens and other is for devices with out it. Am I wrong ? If not should I use both listeners to secure both kind of devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `OnTouch` if you have some event that should only happen with a touch screen.  If you just want to do something when the user taps (or clicks), then you only need `OnClick`.

Comment: ok but what if I want do most flexible app ? If I have simple list it should be usable on touch and nontouch screen. So should I use then both or should I make app for touch only and non touch only ?

Comment: OnClick works for both.  If you do the same action for both types of events, then you only need to implement OnClick.  If you, for some reason, only want a specific action to occur when the user touches the view, then you must implement OnTouch.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Now I get in 100% :)

Answer (score 1):

I use both. I've create a class extending from Button class. I've put my custom appearance and interaction (programmaticaly) on the onTouch() method and the functionality for the onClick().

Comment: Do you get some exta features from using both ?

Comment: Yes, I do functionality on onClick() and drawing (invalidating/redrawing) the element on the onTouch(). Good way to separate what should the compnent do and how should it look like. =]