# How can i get both OnClick and OnTouch Listeners

Tags: android, android-imageview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am in a position to implement different actions for `OnClick` and `OnTouch` listeners for an `ImageView`.I have referred several links in stackoverflow but couldn't achieve my goal. 
how can I implement this.I've referred

[how to use both Ontouch and Onclick for an ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538747/how-to-use-both-ontouch-and-onclick-for-an-imagebutton)

[Android onTouch with onClick and onLongClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387572/android-ontouch-with-onclick-and-onlongclick)

[Can't handle both click and touch events simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159366/cant-handle-both-click-and-touch-events-simultaneously)

[OnTouch/OnClick listeners. Use both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553253/ontouch-onclick-listeners-use-both)

actually my context was when i click on imageview it will goto other activity and when i swipe on it it has to liked by the user.
any help.

Comment: why you want to use ontouch linstener?

Comment: to drag the imageview either left or right(left -meaning user Dislikes the item  & right - user likes it)  and for click action he has to move to other activity to check all the images of that product(item).

Comment: if you use the onTouchListener you can add a gesture detector and override onTap, onLongTap, onFling and the others

Comment: i have used gesturedetector, in that implemented onFling method(swipe right and swipe left used) it is working but onclick is not working at this point...

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("ajay +event.getAction()" + event.getAction());
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                layOutParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                layOutParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = layOutParams.x;
                initialY = layOutParams.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                if (initialTouchX == event.getRawX() && initialTouchY == event.getRawY()) {
                    return false;// to handle Click
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (initialTouchX == event.getRawX() && initialTouchY == event.getRawY()) {
                    return false;// to handle Click
                }
                break;

        }
        return true;

    }
};
```

onClick Implemenation

```
overLayview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("ajay onClick Lisner");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you ajay....I have asked this exactly one year back..(April 7,2014)..I had done this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to implement both behaviors, define MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE and check at ACTION_UP in onTouch, so you will have something like this.

pseudo

```
private static final int MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE=300;
private int oldX,newX;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) // touch down
    {   oldX = event.getX(); //get touch position      }

    else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) // touch up
    {
       newX = event.getX(); //get last touch position 
       if (Math.abs( newX-oldX )> MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE)
           //its a swipe
       else
           // its a click
     }
}
```

Comment: what is oldX and newX?  i mean for different screens how can i give different values for different screens? 
any way Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to decide if the gesture is a swipe or not and act acrodingly

see here how to achieve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/1393632

Comment: it is fine for gesture meaning swipe(Touch)...but click action not working at this situation.