# Android - Handle click and swipe on listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, android-gesture

I am making a menu where the items have to respond to two types of events:

> **OnClick**
>   *If the user clicks the item, it should start an Activity. Each button launches a different activity.*
>
> **OnFling**
>   *When the user swipes the item from right to left, its name should appear. Each item has a different name, and the name will show up just
>   in the item that was swiped*.

I tried a lot of different things, searched for many tutorials and questions here on StackOverflow but I couldn't find a decent answer and my implementation stills poor.

What I am doing right now is setting an `OnClick` handle for each item in the method `getView` of my custom adapter and setting a gestureListener on my listView and handling the method `onFling`, but it is not acting as expected: most of the time I try to swipe and the gesture is handled as a click...

I know I could use an implementation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912291/how-can-i-get-both-onclick-and-ontouch-listeners), but I think **I can not** use the onTouch event trick in this case, because I need the **view position** so I can handle which activity should be launched (onTouch/click) or which `TextView` should become visible.

Here are the snippets that I have so far:

```
    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            new GestureListener());

    lvMenu.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

The inner class:

```
class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    protected MotionEvent mLastOnDownEvent = null;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(final MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2,
            final float velocityX, final float velocityY) {
        Log.d("OnFling", "Called");
        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 20;
        final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("A", "Right to Left");
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.i("B", "Left to Right");
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

And the `onClick()` method inside my custom adapter:

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
                Intent i = null;
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    i = new Intent(parent.getContext(),
                            ProfileActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    i = new Intent(parent.getContext(),
                            CatalogActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    i = new Intent(parent.getContext(), GuideActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    i = new Intent(parent.getContext(),
                            EventsActivity.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("MenuActivity", "Switch default case.");
                    break;
                }
                if (i != null) {
                    parent.getContext().startActivity(i);
                }

            }
```

Thank you :)

**EDIT 1:** now I am trying to set a OnTouchListener to each View in my custom adapter. But it is not working... I can't figure out the reason why.

This is how I am setting up the TouchListener:

```
            convertView.setOnTouchListener(new MenuGestureHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipeRight() {
                Log.d("Swipe Right", "OK!");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                Log.d("Click", "OK!");
            }

        });
```

And this is the class (with some useless code like swipeUp, swipeDown):

```
public class MenuGestureHandler implements OnTouchListener {

GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(final MotionEvent e) {
        onClick(); // my method
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2,
            final float velocityX, final float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            final float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            final float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        result = onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        result = onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        result = onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        result = onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public boolean onSwipeRight() {
    return false;
}

public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
    return false;
}

public void onClick() {
}

public boolean onSwipeTop() {
    return false;
}

public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT 2** I could get it to work by just overriding the method `onDown()` in my GestureListener class and setting it to always return true. I really don't understand why I need to do that, but it seems it is working now!

Answer (score 4):

There may be a few problems to consider here, but the first and foremost is the hierarchy of touch events.

From what I gather, the `GestureDetector` is attached to the `ListView` via an `OnTouchListener`, and the `OnClickListener` is set on the individual list items--which are child views of the `ListView`.

This is a problem because of touch handling order. `ListView` (and really any `ViewGroup`) will deliver touch events to its child views first, and handle the events directly ***if and only if*** no child views consume the event. A child view with an `OnClickListener` will always consume touch events because it is tracking them for a click event...so your existing swipe detector never (or rarely) sees any events.

The simplest solution would likely be to avoid splitting the touch handling between two elements. Use a single `GestureDetector` for each list item that handles both the click (i.e. single tap up) and the swipe--and make sure it's set on the items themselves...not the parent `ListView`.

You might also consider watching my talk on the [Android Touch System](http://crcl.to/2cof6) to give you a more detailed idea of what you are dealing with.

Comment: Alright, perfect. Now I understand the issue... But I cannot attach a OnTouchListener to each item, I don't know why! It just does not work... Can you help me with that? I edited my post with the newest code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question for here is the answer for future searches:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426980/6776960